# Difficulty with COMPOSER_HOME environment var in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the following error updating composer in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment.

```
The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
```

The command causing the error actually sets the environment variable on the same line. It's part of a `.ebextensions` command

```
commands:
  01_update_composer: 
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/var/home && composer.phar self-update
```

How can I fix this? Is there something else that could cause that error?

I have tried setting the environment in this configuration `env:` but that made no difference. I've also added `printenv && composer.phar self-update` and can confirm the variable is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace with this:

`command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11`

There is a composer issue. [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4789)

Comment: In my case the update to the version with the issue had already happened. The above command failed because the buggy version wasn't able to downgrade itself to the non-buggy one. I replaced `COMPOSER_HOME` with `HOME` to work around this.

Comment: I was also using AWS EB. I did another deployment with the fix and then killed the instances. So the new instances will initialize with the fix.